# Add a customer to Quickbooks Online (qbXML)

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-services, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I want to simply add a customer to Quickbooks Online from my .NET app.  What is the best way to do this and what would the code look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do this: you can use [the QuickBooks SDK](http://qbsdk.developer.intuit.com/sdk/qb), construct an add customer XML message and send it to QuickBooks Online Edition (QBOE). Since you're in .NET you can also use the QBFC library which manages the XML for you and provides a structured API which is easier and safer to use than raw XML.

Or you can make a REST call using the [Intuit Partner Platform](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/ipp/federated) (IPP). The REST API for QBOE was still in Beta last I checked, but this is definitely the way of the future and will probably have more full featured support for QBOE eventually (There have always been fewer supported features for QBOE in the SDK vs. the desktop edition).

In both cases you'll have to deal with authentication. For the SDK, you have to authorize the app and get a connection ticket. For the IPP, you'll have to authorize the app and negotiate with the SAML gateway.

If you're just doing a custom application or messing around, you'll probably want to use the SDK because it's easier, particularly the authentication. If you're building a product, IPP is worth a serious look. If you are building a product, you should be aware that Microsoft currently has a support program called Frontrunner that provides some goodies if you use the IPP.

Comment: What would the code look like for the first approach?  I can't seem to find an example of simply adding a customer.

Comment: There is a C# application in the SDK samples that uses qbXML to add a customer to the desktop edition. The qbXML needed for this simple customer add will be identical with the online edition. In order to change the sample application so that it connects with QBOE, you just have to use a remote connection. The procedures for setting up a remote connection are discussed in the SDK documentation under the heading, "Accessing QBOE Using the QBOE Connector."

Answer (score 1):

For QBOE, you can post XML to authenticate and add customers. Here is a link to get started:

[QBOE Integration](http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/archive/2009/10/04/how-to-programmatically-connect-to-quickbooks-online-edition-qboe.aspx)

You'll need to use QBXML v 6, though you can get the XML here:

http://developer.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html

You can use XML Serialization to parse the XML into strongly typed classes, so you can program against them.

I also offer C# kits for QB Desktop, QBOE, and QBPOS, if you are interested.

Comment: +1 for the Quickbooks developer link - their documentation is terrible to navigate.